# Looping in word count

Tags: r

New to r-studio and I have a two column csv file (response, id) whereby the response column has an assigned id number. Ex., rows 1-250 are assigned id 1, rows 251-311 assigned id 2, etc.

Can I write a loop that accepts the id number and R generates word frequencies based on the passed id number? The output would be to new csv file.

Is this do-able? Any examples would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it is!

For instance:

```
# Generate some random data
data <- data.frame(id=rep(1:10, each=200), val=rnorm(2000))
h <- hist(subset(data, id=5)$val, plot=0)
write.csv("output.csv", h$counts)
```

**EDIT**
How this works:

`subset(data, id=5)` will get only the rows for which the column called `id` equals 5.

Now, once we selected only the rows we want (obviously 5 is just an example, you can pass whatever value you want, also in a variable) you get the values which you want to count using the `$` operator.

So `subset(data, id=5)$val` means: take all the rows with id=5 and then consider the column called `val`.

In my example val is an integer so I use the `hist` function to get counts (`plot=0` is only there to suppress the graphical output). If you have strings you can use the `table` function instead.

Finally, `write.csv` outputs the result to a csv file. See `?write.csv` or `?write.table` for extensive help on the (many) options of these functions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Since I'm new to this program can you provide further enlightenment on the code you provided? Also, is it possible to use a "for-loop"?

Comment: Added a few informations. As for the `for` loop, yes there is a `for ... in ...` construct. I would suggest checking the [manual section on CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/manuals.html), especially the contributed documentation. There are a lot of good manuals for beginning using R.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed description and I'll check out the R manuals.

Answer (score 1):

I may be mis-reading the original question, but OP asks for word counts that correspond to the groups of assigned id numbers.

If so, would not `dplyr` and a regex to count words address the need?  Something like:

```
new.df <- data %.%  # start with the two-column data frame of id and word strings
  group_by(id) %.%  # aggregate the ids, e.g. id1, id2
  summarise(WordCount = gsub("^.*\\s", "", dataResponse) # count all the words in the 2nd column.  There are multiple ways to count words.
```